Computing trends on data with missing value
I am collecting some feedback from my users. There is no guarantee that all users will offer feedback. So in every time period, there will be a lot of feedback forms with no feedback value.
I want to identify trends and outliers on the feedback values I collect through the form. What would be the best approach to compute them considering a large portion of the data is missing.
One of the way missing values affect the problem is that a reduction in number of "Bad" or "Good" feedback doesn't necessarily mean a change in the feedback. It is possible that a less number of people responded to the form. How do I handle missing data in a scenario like this?

Is there a reason you can't compute averages/fractions? i.e. the portion of total reviews marked "bad" or "good"
